# Theme Customization with WP CLI

Tags: theme-customizer, wp-cli

It seems we cannot say Hi here,

However, I search on the documentation, and the github, however i don't find any information about customization of theme through WP CLI.
Is it possible to do the same job as we do with visual interface but in line command ?

Thanks

Neuron

Comment: Theme options are here: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/theme/

Comment: Yes I know what basic options exist. What I need is to customize with wp cli, maybe specific command could be created to do that however I just some info to start.

Comment: You are going to need to be specific and define what you need to edit and show some of your own research - if not, it will be hard for others to help you find good answers.